# Run series of script (.sql) file using entity framework in a console application

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have 5 .sql script files in my .net console application each script file represent a step .I want to execute each of them using entity framework 
Note i have INSERT,GO,SET IDENTITY_INSERT,ALTER TABLE statement in my script file

```
Example sql file 1
--Add divsional settings
DECLARE @DIVISIONID int= 29 --Roadshow hardocing it because it may b use somewhere in the code
DECLARE @US_DIVISION_PROFILEID INT = 1;
DECLARE @CANADA_DIVISION_PROFILEID INT = 2;
DECLARE @GLOBALSITEID INT =1
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME= GETDATE()

EXEC spInsertPayWeeks @GLOBALSITEID,@DATE


--Generate (current,previous,next) wo week rotation  set monday as a first day of rotation
DECLARE @PREVIOUS_ROTATION_START DATETIME= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 13, GETDATE()), 0)
DECLARE @PREVIOUS_ROTATION_END DATETIME= dateadd(dd,13,@PREVIOUS_ROTATION_START) --Add 13 days to rotation

DECLARE @CURRENT_ROTATION_START DATETIME= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 5, GETDATE()), 0)
DECLARE @CURRENT_ROTATION_END DATETIME= dateadd(dd,13,@CURRENT_ROTATION_START) --Add 13 days to rotation

DECLARE @NEXT_ROTATION_START DATETIME= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, -13, GETDATE()), 0)
DECLARE @NEXT_ROTATION_END DATETIME= dateadd(dd,13,@NEXT_ROTATION_START) --Add 13 days to rotation


---insert division profile rotation 
INSERT INTO DivisionProfileRotation(DivisionProfileID,StartDate,EndDate) VALUES (@US_DIVISION_PROFILEID,@PREVIOUS_ROTATION_START,@PREVIOUS_ROTATION_END)
INSERT INTO DivisionProfileRotation(DivisionProfileID,StartDate,EndDate) VALUES (@US_DIVISION_PROFILEID,@CURRENT_ROTATION_START,@CURRENT_ROTATION_END)
INSERT INTO DivisionProfileRotation(DivisionProfileID,StartDate,EndDate) VALUES (@US_DIVISION_PROFILEID,@NEXT_ROTATION_START,@NEXT_ROTATION_END)

INSERT INTO DivisionProfileRotation(DivisionProfileID,StartDate,EndDate) VALUES (@CANADA_DIVISION_PROFILEID,@PREVIOUS_ROTATION_START,@PREVIOUS_ROTATION_END)
INSERT INTO DivisionProfileRotation(DivisionProfileID,StartDate,EndDate) VALUES (@CANADA_DIVISION_PROFILEID,@CURRENT_ROTATION_START,@CURRENT_ROTATION_END)
INSERT INTO DivisionProfileRotation(DivisionProfileID,StartDate,EndDate) VALUES (@CANADA_DIVISION_PROFILEID,@NEXT_ROTATION_START,@NEXT_ROTATION_END)

DECLARE @ICD_OFFICE_CORPORATION_ADDRESS_ID_ONE INT= 1;
DECLARE @ICD_OFFICE_CORPORATION_ADDRESS_ID_TWO INT = 2;

--Set up two corporation with each office
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[IcdCorporation] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[IcdOffice]  NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
```

Comment: Basically you want to execute all the SQL queries in your 5 files using Entity Framework ?

Comment: @WaleedNaveed yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something by my self using entity framework and its working for me. I hope it helps someone.

Here is my helper class that is taking care of all the extra functions that i need  :

```
 public static class Helper
    {
        private const string SCRIPT_FOLDER = @"\Scripts\";
        public static string GetSqlStatmentsFromFile(string filename)
        {
            var folderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + SCRIPT_FOLDER;
            if (Directory.Exists(folderPath) && File.Exists(folderPath + filename))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(folderPath + filename))
                {
                    return reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }

        public static string UpdateSqlParameters(IDictionary<string, string> parameters, string sql)
        {
            var sqlString = new StringBuilder(sql);
            foreach (var param in parameters)
            {
                sqlString = sqlString.Replace(param.Key, param.Value);
            }
            return sqlString.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Here is my Program.cs

```
 class Program
    {
        public const int GLOBAL_SITE_ID = 1;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExecuteSteps();
        }

        private static void ExecuteSteps()
        {  
            //My entity framework context
            TestEntities context=new TestEntities();

            foreach (var step in GetSteps())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(step.StepName + "...");
                if (step.IsScript && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(step.ScriptFilePath))
                {
                    var sql = Helper.UpdateSqlParameters(GetGlobalParameters(), Helper.GetSqlStatmentsFromFile(step.ScriptFilePath));
                    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);
                }
                Console.WriteLine(step.StepName + " Completed.");
            }
        }


        private static IEnumerable<Step> GetSteps()
        {
            return new List<Step>
            {
                new Step{ StepName = "Cleaning Database", IsScript =true, ScriptFilePath="CleanDatabase.sql"},
                new Step{ StepName = "Filling master data into database", IsScript =true, ScriptFilePath="FillMasterData.sql"},
                new Step{ StepName = "Adding default data to the system", IsScript =true, ScriptFilePath="AddDefaultData.sql"},
                new Step{ StepName = "Adding menus", IsScript =true, ScriptFilePath="AddMenusAndPermissions.sql"},
            };
        }

        private static IDictionary<string, string> GetGlobalParameters()
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"@_GLOBAL_SITE_ID",GLOBAL_SITE_ID.ToString() }
            };
        }
    }
```

Note that Scripts files are in the script folder of the application and the sql files inside it are  defined to be copied over to bin folder and their build action is content